# Subselection using np.logical_and in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I plot(x,y) a chart and want to return True when for x ranging from A to B y is larger than C ("there exists x in interval such that y(x) > C). The code below does not work. How can I do it?

```
d_for_hours=density[np.logical_and(y>C,x>=A, x <=B)].all()
```

Exemplary output:

for C = 0.02 and A = 9 and B = 13, the output should be True

for C = 0.05 and A = 9 and B = 13, the output should be False

[image]

Comment: Please provide an example with desired output.

Comment: Please rephrase your question (you'll want to avoid saying things like "when for x ranging from A to B y is larger than C". See [ask]. Also, your code seems to be missing a ')'. Use:
`d_for_hours=density[np.logical_and(y>C,x>=A, x <=B)].all()`

Comment: @IanS Exemplary output:

for C = 0.02 and A = 9 and B = 13, the output should be True

for C = 0.05 and A = 9 and B = 13, the output should be False

Comment: @MahendranNadesan Re-named the question and added a missing bracket.

Comment: And why does your code not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `any` rather than `all` to check if `y` has any value above `C`. Before that, you need to restrict `y` to the indices of `x` that match the condition (between `A` and `B`):

```
# create data
x = np.array(range(20))
y = np.array(19 * [0] + [1])

(y[np.logical_and(x>=9, x<=13)] >= 0.05).any()  # False
(y[np.logical_and(x>=9, x<=20)] >= 0.05).any()  # True
```